# What are the attributes to specify in the 5th parameter of ScannerOpen of Hbase?

Tags: python, hbase, thrift

I have installed HBase and configured thrift server using link http://whynosql.com/using-thrift-python-client-with-hbase/. I don't know what attributes to specify when  i call ScannerOpen whose prototype in Hbase.py is as follows

```
def scannerOpen(self, tableName, startRow, columns, attributes):
```

so can anybody please let me know what attributes i can specify their and whats their respective meaning?

Answer (score 0):

you and me both, bud ... you like me were probably using the most recent Hbase.thrift definition file, which has 4 (5 if you include 'self'), but all the docs talk about 3 - the "attributes" parameter has sneaked in, and if anyone knows how to use it, they're not saying ...

In the end, I found an older version here:
https://github.com/wbolster/happybase/blob/master/happybase/Hbase.thrift

this is how I use it, taking from the HBase In Action example:

```
>>> import thrift
>>> import hbase
>>> from thrift.transport import TSocket
>>> from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
>>> from hbase import Hbase
>>> transport =TSocket.TSocket("yeps85228", 9090)
>>> protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
>>> client = Hbase.Client(protocol)
>>> transport.open()
>>> client.getTableNames()
['followedBy', 'follows', 'twits', 'users']
>>> columns = ['info:user', 'info:name','info:email']
>>> scanner = client.scannerOpen('users','',columns)
>>> scanner
1
>>> row = client.scannerGet(scanner)
>>> row
[TRowResult(columns={'info:email': TCell(timestamp=1382538013868L, value=' Andre
w19@pangane.com'), 'info:name': TCell(timestamp=1382538013868L, value='Casey And
rew'), 'info:user': TCell(timestamp=1382538013868L, value=' Andrew19')}, row=' A
ndrew19')]
```

hope that helps

Comment: Hi Toby evans, thanks for your reply. I got that but my problem is with the 4th parameter (excluding self). I don't know its usage. If anyone knows how to use it please explain me its usage.